# Линейная экстраполяция в двумерном пространстве. - Линейная аппроксимация табличной функции двух переменных

Tags: математика

Есть двумерное пространство и есть массив, состоящий из `x`, `y` и `v`: две координаты и значение. Как на основе имеющихся значений рассчитать новые значения для произвольных координат?

Говорят, это решается с помощью методов линейной экстраполяции. Подскажите, где взять формулу или исходный код программы для такого примитивного случая как мой?

Comment: Насколько я помню, доказательство равномощности отрезка и квадрата (куба и т.п.), со стороной 1, опирается на лемму о том, что если А - подмножество Б и Б - подмножество А, то они равномощны (где А и Б - бесконечные множества).

И приведение квадрата к отрезку делается так: для каждой точки квадрата (0.x1x2x3x4... 0.y1y2y3y4...) в соответствие ставится точка на отрезке 0.x1y1x2y2x3y3x4y4... .

Comment: И при этом на отрезке остается бесконечное множество точек вида 0.x19x29x39... - которым при таком отображении не соответствует ни одна точка квадрата (т.к. x.(9) = x+1, и 9 в периоде - невозможное отображение для координаты). Таким образом, множество точек квадрата могут быть "перенесены" на подмножество точек отрезка.

Тогда способ приведения множества точек куба к множеству точек квадрата становится очевидным. И приведение множества точек N-мерного куба тоже.

Возможно, Вам следует воспользоваться чем-то таким?

Comment: Сетка по x,y равномерная (например, прямоугольная)?

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим задачу линейной аппроксимации таблично заданной функции двух переменных.

---

ПОСТАНОВКА ЗАДАЧИ

Функция u(x, y) задана своими значениями u<sub>i</sub> в точках с координатами (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>), i = 0, 1, … n-1.

Требуется определить коэффициенты A, B, C линейной аппроксимирующей функции
U(x, y) = Ax + By + C,
минимизирующие невязку
δ(A, B, C) = ∑<sub>i</sub> (Ax<sub>i</sub> + By<sub>i</sub> + C - v<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>.

---

РЕШЕНИЕ

Функция невязки зависит от трёх переменных A, B, C. Необходимые условия минимума этой функции - нулевые частные производные по каждой из этих переменных:
δ'<sub>A</sub> = 0; δ'<sub>B</sub> = 0; δ'<sub>C</sub> = 0.
Эти условия приводят к СЛАУ 3-го порядка:

2∑<sub>i</sub> (Ax<sub>i</sub> + By<sub>i</sub> + C - v<sub>i</sub>)x<sub>i</sub> = 0;
2∑<sub>i</sub> (Ax<sub>i</sub> + By<sub>i</sub> + C - v<sub>i</sub>)y<sub>i</sub> = 0;
2∑<sub>i</sub> (Ax<sub>i</sub> + By<sub>i</sub> + C - v<sub>i</sub>) = 0,

∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>·A + ∑<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>·B + ∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>z<sub>i</sub>·C = ∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>,

∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>·A + ∑ y<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>·B + ∑<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>z<sub>i</sub>·C = ∑ <sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>,

∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>z<sub>i</sub>· A + ∑ y<sub>i</sub>z<sub>i</sub>·B + ∑z<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>·C = ∑ <sub>i</sub> z<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>,

решение которой (например, по правилу Крамера) проблемы не представляет.